# iOS Time-based notifications?

Tags: ios, cocoa, notifications

Is it possible to listen for time-specific notifications (for example, every second, every minute, at 5am, at 11:45 and so on) in iOS using default components? Or should I use some adhoc solution?

Comment: initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

Answer (score 3):

Not like that, you need to add yourself you own way of calling a method every period of time, use NSTimer or UILocalNotifications for that:

[NSTimer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

[UILocalNotification Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For example, create a timer and repeat it every 5 min, or everyday at 11:45... or send a notification every day at 5am, etc...